# How to check if a character appears in a string exactly one time or multiple times?

Tags: ruby

So say I have three strings.  I am trying to check if the letters in two appear EXACTLY ONCE in "doopdedoo", and if the letters in three appear an unlimited amount of times.

```
one = "doopdedoo"
two = "dp"
three = "o"

if one.{|a| a.chars.all? {|c| "#{three}".include?(c)}} &&  one.{|a| a.chars.once? {|c| "#{two}".include?(c)}}
```

I have used the above to test for the presence of an unlimited amount of o's.  How to test for a limited amount of d's and p's?

Edit:

Sorry but I need to clarify.  My expected output would be nothing for this case.

```
[]
```

Because doopdeedoo contains more than one instance of d or p.

It does contain many o's, so that's fine.

I also added the &&... part to the method above.  I realize there is no 'once' method but if there is something like that I'd like to use it.

Comment: There **is** a [one?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F) method.

Comment: The code isn't even valid ruby--it results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`String#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-count) method like this:

```
test_string = "foopaad"
must_appear_once = ['d', 'p']
must_appear = ['o']

must_appear_once.all? {|c| test_string.count(c) == 1} \
and must_appear.all? {|c| test_string.count(c) > 0}
```

This ensures that `'d'` and `'p'` each appear exacly once and that `'o'` appears in the string (no matter how often).

Comment: Myself don't understand the question.. :( What is OP looking for..

Comment: I guess he wants to know how often certain characters appear in a string and test for that.

Comment: See edits - not quite what I was looking for, thanks though :)

Comment: please, have a look at my edit - is this the way you thought it should work?